# « Ellipsis » et « points de suspension »

Tags: terminologie, typographie

Peut-on utiliser le mot « *ellipsis* » pour signifier *points de suspension* ? Sinon, existe-t-il des raisons pour expliquer cette différence entre les terminologies anglaise et française ?

Comment: Pourquoi utiliser le mot anglais « ellipsis » et pas sa traduction française « ellipse » ?

Comment: @LPH https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis Not to be confused with Ellipse.

An ellipsis (plural ellipses; from the Ancient Greek: ἔλλειψις, élleipsis, 'omission' or 'falling short') is a series of dots (typically three, such as "…") that usually indicates an intentional omission of a word, sentence, or whole section from a text without altering its original meaning.[...]

Comment: Il faudrait alors que « ellipsis » soit entre guillemets dans votre texte, puisque ce n'est pas dans la langue.

Comment: @Laure, Merci. Naïvité de ma part. J'aurais dû chercher plus ! Merci. Alors on peut dire ellipse pour points de suspension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Ellipsis*** est un mot anglais (latin) inutilisé en français.

***Points de suspension*** est l'expression consacrée pour désigner les trois points rapprochés qui indiquent l'omission d'un ou plusieurs mots dans une phrase ou une liste,  mais qui peuvent aussi marquer une hésitation ou une interruption dans le discours.

Je n'ai jamais entendu personne en France employer ***ellipse*** (qui est un mot féminin) pour désigner les points de suspension eux-mêmes et considère cet usage, s'il existe, comme un anglicisme. Rien ne permet de penser que ce n'est pas aussi le cas au Canada francophone ou ailleurs. Le sens largement le plus courant d'*ellipse* est celui d'une courbe géométrique fermée, comme en anglais. *Ellipse* désigne aussi une figure de style qui omet une partie de phrase mais cette omission n'est pas nécessairement marquée par des points de suspension. Je ne recommanderais donc pas d'utiliser *ellipse* pour désigner ces derniers.

Comment: En tant que Français, je suis d'accord, c'est un anglicisme. Mais [les Québecois disent apparemment « ellipse » et pas « points de suspension »](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=ELLIPSIS&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs).

Comment: @Gilles Il faudrait connaître l'avis des intéressés. Je ne vois pas de différence d'usage sur le site de l'OQLF : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3396 et http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3213

Answer (score 3):

*Ellipse* en français et *ellipsis* en anglais ont la même étymologie : du grec *ελλειψις* via le latin *ellipsis*. Comme dans la plupart des mots français, la dernière syllabe qui se déclinait est devenue un simple -e muet. On ne dit pas plus *ellipsis* pour une ellipse que *parabola* pour une parabole *tabula* pour une table.

*Ellipse* et *ellipsis* ont tous les deux le sens d'une omission. En revanche, le signe typographique ... qui peut dénoter une omission ne s'appelle pas *ellipse* en France, mais *[points de suspension](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/points_de_suspension)* (toujours au pluriel). En France, une ellipse, c'est « [image: U+2B2D WHITE HORIZONTAL ELLIPSE]) » (⬭ pour ceux qui ont une police Unicode bien fournie) et jamais « ... ». Au Canada francophone, [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=ELLIPSIS&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) et le [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8432621) mentionnent aussi *ellipse*, mais la [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3396) ne mentionne que la terminologie connue en France. Le [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/suspension) donne quelques informations sur l'origine de cette expression :

> 1752 ([Trév.](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_Tr%C3%A9voux/6e_%C3%A9dition,_1771): Suspension, [En termes de Grammaire, on appelle suspension, un certain repos très-marqué, où le sens est interrompu brusquement, et n'est point achevé. Ces sortes de suspensions se marquent par trois ou quatre points de suite](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CshKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1937&lpg=PA1937&dq=%22En+termes+de+Grammaire,+on+appelle+suspension%22)); 1846 points de suspension ([Besch.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bescherelle), s.v. ponctuation)

En France, c'est donc l'utilisation de ... pour indiquer une pause qui a donné son nom au signe typographique. En anglais et au Québec, c'est l'utilisation de ... pour indiquer une omission. Ceci reflète une différence de culture littéraire et typographique. Un [article de Pedro Uribe Echeverria dans *L'Express*](https://www.lexpress.fr/culture/points-d-exclamation-et-de-suspension-cris-et-chuchotements_777714.html) donne quelques éléments historiques.

> Les points de suspension ont eux été popularisés au début du XVIIe siècle par le théâtre imprimé. D'après le chercheur Alain Riffaud, une suite de points est apparue aux éditeurs comme une solution typographique pour représenter l'interruption dans un dialogue [...]. Au XVIIIe siècle, ce « point d'omission »  ou « point interrompu » peut encore compter plus de trois points. L'anglais trouve à ce signe un petit air étranger, puisque l'un de ses noms est *French dots* ; il leur préfère le tiret.

Pour l'anglais, il faudrait se référer à [*Ellipsis in English Literature* de Anne Toner](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/ellipsis-in-english-literature/BF7BEB684BDA9B671C11BA0899B2A4BA). Je me suis contenté du [résumé d'un chercheur de l'Université de Cambridge](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/features/dot-dot-dot-how-the-ellipsis-made-its-mark), qui indique que les premiers usages dénotaient une interruption et n'explique pas comment le signe a évolué pour indiquer l'omission. Le nom du symbole n'était pas fixé au début, pas plus que sa forme (il pouvait s'agir de points, de traits ou d'astérisques, ou encore d'un seul trait long), mais il s'est appelé *eclipsis* (éclipse : le discours disparaît) avant de s'appeler *ellipsis* (ellipse : le discours est omis). Le français de France n'a jamais beaucoup connu les variantes typographiques autres que des points et a continué à considérer le symbole comme indiquant avant tout la suspension et non l'omission du discours.

Le mot *ellipse* désigne aussi la figure géométrique appelée *ellipse* en anglais (allez savoir pourquoi ce n'est pas *ellipsis* ; c'est hors sujet ici).

Comment: @personne Bonne idée, c'est fait.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais plutôt que c'est le contraire: ce sont les points de suspension qui représentent une [ellipse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(rh%C3%A9torique)) (du latin *ellipsis*, omission, lui-même du grec *ἔλλειψις*, manque).

L'ellipse est une figure de style qui désigne une omission aussi bien dans la langue écrite qu'au cinéma.

Answer (score 1):

Il se trouve que l'on utilise aussi le mot « ellipse » pour les points de suspension ([wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ellipse)).

Comment: Effectivement, [au Québec](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=ELLIPSIS&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). Mais pas en France.